# IntelliJ build project (Ctrl + F9) failed Error: 0

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

I have a `LibGDX` project [created by gdx-setup.jar file](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle#creating-a-libgdx-project). I recently run into an issue when build the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, IntelliJ always returns error message: `Error: 0` (see image bellow).

Basically I don't know what IntelliJ does when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and the error message is too short so I don't know how to google for this error. Anyone help me to figure out why this happens please.

[image]

Comment: Graphics Driver that you have ?

Comment: On windows Ctrl + F9,  Make project (compile modifed and dependent)

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Yes I have driver for my graphics card (NVIDIA v378.92).
Does `Ctrl + F9` invoke any gradle task or bind to any command that configurable?

Comment: Have you tried to run on Android platform ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I have removed all untracked files by LibGDX [.gitignore](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/.gitignore) then the project continues to build successfully again but I am pretty sure that it would fail when switch to Android also.

Comment: what is the connection between `.gitignore` and project building. I think `.gitignore` is part of VCS. Are you using VCS in your project ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Yes I use Git for my project. Remove untracked files by `.gitignore` include `.gradle` and `.idea` folders in the root folder (any many other files and folders auto generated when build the project). I think those folders affect the build process.

Comment: When we add files/folder into `.gitignore`, git stops indexing that files and not  include in staging area, but that file still exit in file system so I think that may not be cause of building problem.